mongoose.Types.ObjectId is deprecated
I am using a mongoose model in  my nodejs application
In the below code snippet
userID = req.user.id
const uid = new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(userId)
if(course.StudentsEnrolled.includes(uid)){
// business logic
}


Here the userId will be in form of a String
But I am getting a dashed line in my "ObjectId" saying
The signature '(inputId: number): ObjectId' of 'mongoose.Types.ObjectId' is deprecated.ts(6387)
bson.d.ts(1030, 8): The declaration was marked as deprecated here.
I want to know why this is happening with me, As I didn't find any solution online

mongoose.Types.ObjectId() accepts a 24 character hexadecimal string value for the new ObjectId or an integer value, in seconds from Unix epoch. You are creating a variable userID but are passing userId - note the case difference. Pass userID or req.user.id instead. You might want to do a mongoose.isObjectIdOrHexString(req.user.id) first and then handle control flow based on a true/false result.

If the userID is hexString, you can use this method:
const uid = mongoose.Types.ObjectId.createFromHexString(userId)

You can also use these methods in other use cases:
mongoose.Types.ObjectId.createFromBase64(stringInput)
mongoose.Types.ObjectId.createFromTime(numberInput)

